# ssl.SSLError: [SSL:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] while running in uwsgi

Tags: python, ssl, uwsgi, pygithub

I am using the pyGithub plugin. When running in a normal python process, I am able to access Github appropriately. When running within the context of uwsgi, I get:

> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake()
>   ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)

Any ideas?  I have been hunting this down for a couple of hours now, any feedback would be great.

Sample code:

```
from github import Github
g = Github(USER, PASSWORD)
g.get_repo("<repo name>")
```

Again, when running this basic code in even the python interpreter, everything is fine, I get the repo.  Running inside of a UWSGI environment, I get the above error. I have verified that the virtualenvs used in both cases are the same. Same python interpreter (2.7.10) on a Mac OS X.

Thanks.

**update:**
Turns out, Mac OS X El Capitan was the issue. Headers were changed for the ssl module, and uwsgi was not built properly with it. I still can't install uwsgi via pip, but brew install was able to do it.

I also had to install the OS X 10.10 command line tools before everything started to work.